# Spring define a request scoped bean that has access to the request object

Tags: java, spring, guice

I am migrating a Java application that uses guice and guice-servlet libraries for DI to Spring(both as a web framework and DI).

I have the following code with GUICE that i need to migrate:

```
import com.google.inject.servlet.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Provider;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RequestScoped
public class CurrentUserProvider implements Provider<User> {

  private static final String CURRENT_USER_HEADER = "x-current-user";

  @Inject
  private Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider;

  @Override
  public User get() {
    return new User(requestProvider.get().getHeader(CURRENT_USER_HEADER));
  }
}
```

And in my Guice module i have something like:
`bind(User.class).toProvider(CurrentUserProvider.class);` which basically enables me to inject a `User` object with the current user anywhere in my app.

Basically the idea is to have a request scoped bean which takes info from the header of the request. I saw that in Spring there is a similar annotation as in Guice for request scoping.

What i don't understand is:
**How to create a bean that has access to the headers of the current request(even if it's a Spring object)?**
Limitations: I want to be able to do this with Java annotations(not with XML)
Bonus: I it can somehow work with the existing provider it would be great.

Comment: Why you don't want to read header from the `@Controller`? So `User` bean don't be attached to http request object.

Comment: Well because it's corporate code(it's more complex that just taking one header). Also i want the PR that changes Guice -> Spring to be smaller and don't want to decorate every controller. Other than the solution you propose is shorter and cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten `@Component` to ask Spring to consider that class a bean. Then you need `@Autowired` not `@Inject` to ask for `HttpServletRequest` to be injected. According to documentation all spring beans of Request scope can ask for `HttpServletRequest` to be injected.

As for provider you don't even need it to read that request. You can read it directly from HttpServletRequest

```
@Component
@RequestScoped
public class CurrentUserProvider implements Provider<User> {

  private static final String CURRENT_USER_HEADER = "x-current-user";

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

  @Override
  public User get() {
  return new User(httpServletRequest.getHeader(CURRENT_USER_HEADER));
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Unfortunatelly i still don't know how to inject this provider in my controller? I tried with @Autowired Provider<User> userProvider in my controller class, but it failed with No qualifying bean of type 'com..management.user.User'.

Comment: just use `@Autowired CurrentUserProvider currentUserProvider`

Comment: I figured it out actually, i need to have a /@Bean that returns User and then i can have /@Autowired Provider<User>

Comment: Ah yeah i guess your thing works as well :)